# Is it safe to modify data of pointer in vector from another thread?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, thread-safety

Things seem to be working but I'm unsure if this is the best way to go about it.

Basically I have an object which does asynchronous retrieval of data.  This object has a vector of pointers which are allocated and de-allocated on the main thread.  Using boost functions a process results callback is bound with one of the pointers in this vector.  When it fires it will be running on some arbitrary thread and modify the data of the pointer.

Now I have critical sections around the parts that are pushing into the vector and erasing in case the asynch retrieval object is receives more requests but I'm wondering if I need some kind of guard in the callback that is modifying the pointer data as well.

Hopefully this slimmed down pseudo code makes things more clear:

```
class CAsyncRetriever
{
    // typedefs of boost functions

    class DataObject
    {
         // methods and members
    };

public:
    // Start single asynch retrieve with completion callback
    void Start(SomeArgs)
    {
        SetupRetrieve(SomeArgs);
        LaunchRetrieves();
    }

protected:
    void SetupRetrieve(SomeArgs)
    {
            // ...

        { // scope for data lock
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_dataMutex);
            m_inProgress.push_back(SmartPtr<DataObject>(new DataObject)));
            m_callback = boost::bind(&CAsyncRetriever::ProcessResults, this, _1, m_inProgress.back());
        }

            // ...
    }

    void ProcessResults(DataObject* data)
    {
                // CALLED ON ANOTHER THREAD ... IS THIS SAFE?
        data->m_SomeMember.SomeMethod();
                data->m_SomeOtherMember = SomeStuff;
    }

    void Cleanup()
    {
                // ...

        { // scope for data lock
            boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(m_dataMutex);
            while(!m_inProgress.empty() && m_inProgress.front()->IsComplete())
                m_inProgress.erase(m_inProgress.begin());
        }

                // ...
         }

private:
    std::vector<SmartPtr<DataObject>> m_inProgress;
    boost::mutex m_dataMutex;
        // other members
};
```

Edit: This is the actual code for the ProccessResults callback (plus comments for your benefit)

```
    void ProcessResults(CRetrieveResults* pRetrieveResults, CRetData* data)
        {
// pRetrieveResults is delayed binding that server passes in when invoking callback in thread pool
// data is raw pointer to ref counted object in vector of main thread (the DataObject* in question)

                // if there was an error set the code on the atomic int in object
            data->m_nErrorCode.Store_Release(pRetrieveResults->GetErrorCode());

                // generic iterator of results bindings for generic sotrage class item
            TPackedDataIterator<GenItem::CBind> dataItr(&pRetrieveResults->m_DataIter);
                // namespace function which will iterate results and initialize generic storage
            GenericStorage::InitializeItems<GenItem>(&data->m_items, dataItr, pRetrieveResults->m_nTotalResultsFound); // this is potentially time consuming depending on the amount of results and amount of columns that were bound in storage class definition (i.e.about 8 seconds for a million equipment items in release)
                // atomic uint32_t that is incremented when kicking off async retrieve
            m_nStarted.Decrement(); // this one is done processing

                // boost function completion callback bound to interface that requested results
            data->m_complete(data->m_items);
        }
```

Comment: You need to add more information if you expect a sensible answer. Currently big important bits are missing, in particular, what are and how is `SomeMethod`, `IsComplete`  implemented and how is the *complete* flag raised. If the last line of the processing function is an assignment, unless that is user defined type, and it locks, and it is the one setting `IsComplete` to true, the answer is no, it is not safe. But my guess is that that processing function is just an skeleton.

Comment: yeah a lot of this is a skeleton I just wanted to show that it calls methods and assigns members within it. At this point I'm thinking I will be alright as long as the semantic of only having one thread per callback per pointer remains in place. Incremental asynchronous retrieves introduce a bit too much latency so I'm not worried about that implementation yet.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the approach, but the devil is in the details. Depending on what the actual operations are and how synchronization is performed on the *shared* data (my guess is that the shared data is only a flag checked by `IsComplete`) then it can be correct. Whether it is the best approach or could be simplified is a different issue, but without context it is impossible to tell. Things that might be of importance: is the implementation of `SmartPtr` thread safe? There is a high potential for a race condition there.

Comment: BTW, `ProcessResults` should probably be `static`, if it is not `static` you are *sharing* the `this` pointer, and then you have to also add locks inside `ProcessResults` for each member object.

Comment: You are probably right ... however I think I'll just stop passing the async retriever in the completion callback as it's not really needed and then the only other member used is atomic so that'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't safe.

`ProcessResults` operates on the data structure passed to it through `DataObject`. It indicates that you have shared state between different threads, and if both threads operate on the data structure concurrently you might have some trouble coming your way.

Comment: Only one callback is fired per retrieve. So only one thread accessing the pointer at any time. If you made 5 requests it would allocate 5 objects, make 5 bindings, kick them off, 5 callbacks on 5 other threads would be called to do the dirty work, and then things get cleaned up later the next time you make more requests if they are done.

Comment: Also "doneness" is determined by the callback firing, completing it's processing, and subsequently firing a complete callback at the end of it's execution.

Comment: Ah, the assignments done in the callback kind of "implied" that you're using `DataObject` to pass _another_ structure so that the callback method would work on it. Would you update the question with a bit more details about the semantics of the callback method, i.e. what does it work on and is it shared between threads?

Comment: It's called between threads but my understanding is each thread will have it's own stack so as long as nothing is shared between threads it could be fine ... I'll post the real callback as an edit if you like.

Answer (score 3):

As it stands, it appears that the `Cleanup` code can destroy an object for which a callback to `ProcessResults` is in flight.  That's going to cause problems when you deref the pointer in the callback.

My suggestion would be that you extend the semantics of your `m_dataMutex` to encompass the callback, though if the callback is long-running, or can happen inline within `SetupRetrieve` (sometimes this does happen - though here you state the callback is on a different thread, in which case you are OK) then things are more complex.  Currently `m_dataMutex` is a bit confused about whether it controls access to the vector, or its contents, or both.  With its scope clarified, `ProcessResults` could then be enhanced to verify validity of the payload within the lock.

Comment: That's what the IsComplete method checks no worries there ... I thought of locking in the callback but those are called at an arbitrary time by arbitrary threads as the server completes async tasks. Locking on a single mutex synchronizes and thus makes a bottle neck whereas currently callbacks can be done in parallel.

Comment: @AJG85 - since your callback gets a raw pointer, you absolutely must veify it's still valid before using it. Can you convert the smart pointer to a ref-counting type, and only lock the vector to check it's OK and get a secure reference to the object? Then the bulk of your callback logic can still proceed in parallel.  The other issue is whether the manipulation of the object in callback interferes with any other thread's logic, again that's a problem if so.

Comment: I left out null checks and the majority of code that didn't seem relevant. Also the "SmartPtr" goes by a different name but it is a reference counted object we made that is compatible with STL containers (might phase it out in favor of C++0x someday) ... there is a weak pointer friend class I might be able to use to get a reference but the life of the changes need to last beyond the scope of the callback and thread. Also nothing else can see or use the private object until the end of the process results callback when it fires a completion callback.

Answer (score 0):

Updating a pointer should be an atomic operation, but you can use [`InterlockedExchangePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683609(v=vs.85).aspx) (in Windows) to be sure. Not sure what the Linux equivalent would be.

The only consideration then would be if one thread is using an obsolete pointer. Does the other thread delete the object pointed to by the original pointer? If so, you have a definite problem.

Comment: It isn't updating a pointer, `ProcessResults` _operates_ on the data structure passed to it.

Comment: @Khaled: It's a pointer but it does call methods and change members of the object that the pointer points to.

Comment: So I need to use an atomic pointer? I don't need to swap or change what the pointer is pointing to just use it. Also the other thread doesn't delete anything as deallocating what was created on another thread sounds like bad news any day of the week.

Comment: @AJG85: I meant: "The problem isn't about updating a pointer", looking at my previous comment's wording I admit that it's confusing. Anyhow, the real issue seems to be in the callback function.